# How to identify what is preventing Composer from installing latest version of a package?

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm using the Composer Dependency Manager for PHP and it won't install the latest version of a package. How can I identify what is holding back composer from installing the latest version?

For example, I have `symfony/console` in the `composer.json` versioned as:

```
"symfony/console": "~3.1",
```

If I run `composer outdated` it shows I have `symfony/console` version 3.1.4 installed, and that version 3.3.5 is available and semver-compatible.

```
$ composer outdated --no-ansi
symfony/console                    v3.1.4  ! v3.3.5  Symfony Console Component
```

However, if I perform a dry-run of the update, it will only being me up as far as version 3.2.12.

```
$ composer update --dry-run --with-dependencies symfony/console
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 2 installs, 2 updates, 0 removals
  - Updating symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.2.0) to symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.4.0)
  - Installing psr/log (1.0.2)
  - Installing symfony/debug (v3.3.5)
  - Updating symfony/console (v3.1.4) to symfony/console (v3.2.12)
```

How can I identify what is holding `symfony/console` back at version 3.2.12 when 3.3.5 is the latest?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `prohibits` or `why-not` command will show what is blocking a version.

```
$ composer prohibits symfony/console 3.3.5
symfony/console  v3.3.5 conflicts  symfony/dependency-injection (<3.3)
```

Documentation [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#prohibits-why-not-).