# Composer: how know a working version for package

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-8

I have a question: I am working in a Laravel project with php7.4. Now I have updated my server to php8.0, but when I do `composer update` I get several errors like:

```
Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires symfony/translation 4.3.8 -> satisfiable by symfony/translation[v4.3.8].
    - symfony/translation v4.3.8 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (8.0.19) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

What is a good way to detect the minimal working version for all this packages? Now I try to find the Github-packages and try to find the requirements, but thats a lot of work. Is there a smart way to update this packages?

Comment: post your `composer.json`'s `require` block

Comment: Remove and add package without version - if version with requirements exists - all be ok.

Comment: @Maksim that is the way how I do it now. But I am not happy with this way. Is there no faster/better way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to identify what is preventing Composer from installing latest version of a package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45386572/how-to-identify-what-is-preventing-composer-from-installing-latest-version-of-a)

Comment: Try this https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#reinstall

Comment: No sorry. Both links are no answer. When I do composer reinstall, then composer installs the same version. And when I use composer prohibits, then I have to know the new version number, and I don't know this.

Comment: `Root composer.json requires symfony/translation 4.3.8` - that version constraint is already too strict, and Symfony 4.3 is out of support since more than two years. Why not simply start updating to Symfony 4.4? This should be pretty simple and well documented, and 4.4 supports PHP 8